# Strange Google Chrome Background Image bug when closing modal (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Chrome if you scroll down so the header is half way crossing your browser and you you click the Watch Video button which opens up the modal which is normal but upon closing it if you scroll up I get this strange interference with the background image and also the button, like the background image is cut off and the button adds crazy background with a border on it?

Has anyone experienced this before and know of a fix, only in chrome

Website: http://goo.gl/s3kLML

Screenshot example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3mLz.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a background-attachment: fixed + background-size: cover bug, just remove "fixed" in your background property, it will works.

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url(../images/bg_blur2.jpg) #e8df06 center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Or if you want your background to be fixed in all other browser and just fix this bug in Chrome, you can try :

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.jumbotron {
  background: url(../images/bg_blur2.jpg) #e8df06 center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: You sir a mother f**cking G.